# PhpStorm automatically ignore files from .gitignore

Tags: ide, editor, phpstorm

I'm new to PhpStorm, and I'm trying to get it to automatically ignore files specified in my .gitignore file when adding a file tree to git. I know you can add ignore rules to PhpStorm itself, but I want it to use the rules from my .gitignore file.

Basically I already have a .gitignore file with ignore rules, I just want PhpStorm to follow those rules when adding files (git add) so that none of the files matching the .gitignore rules will be accidentally added to a commit.

Comment: Try to install .ignore plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495

Comment: I already have this plugin installed. When I select my project root folder and add all files, it still adds files that are ignored by my .gitignore file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know in the past this has happened to me as well, so it seems a bit fragile. I never do a `git add` for the entire directory since it has done things like add files in the /vendor directory (which is always in the gitignore file).

But having said that, I was curious, so I did a test as I think it might be related to when things happen (like when git is engaged, or when the .gitignore is added).

I did the following steps on a new project and it worked appropriately, so maybe that will help, you can give it a try and see if it works for you as well. I am working with 2016.1.2

- Create the project
- Select VCS...`Enable Version Control Integration` and select `Git`
- Create the .`gitignore` in the root directory
- In the project, create a new directory called `ignore`
- In the `.gitignore`, add `ignore/` and the ignore directory should turn light gray
- Create `a.txt` in the root directory
- create `b.txt` in the /ignore directory
- right click on whole project and select `git add` and `b.txt` under the ignore directory is not added, but a.txt is